# Change of measure defined by Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: probability, measure-theory, martingales, radon-nikodym

Suppose $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$ is a nonnegative discrete-time martingale with $X_0=1$. Then we know by martingale convergence theorem that $X_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n$ exists.

Let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{X_0,\cdots,X_n\}$. Define new measure $Q$ on $\mathcal{F}_n$ by $Q(V)=E_P[X_n\mathbb{1}_V]$ for $V\in\mathcal{F}_n$. Then by dominated convergence theorem we know that if $E_P[X_\infty]=1$, then $Q\{\sup_nX_n=\infty\}=0$ and $Q\{\sup_nX_n=\infty\}=0$. Now I wonder if the converse can also be shown. Namely, if $Q\{\sup_nX_n=\infty\}=0$ or $Q\{X_\infty=\infty\}=0$, does it hold that $E_P[X_\infty]=1$? Why or why not?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are defining $Q$ only on $\mathcal F_n$ how do $Q\{\sup_nX_n=\infty\}$ or $Q\{X_\infty=\infty\}$ make sense?

Comment: Sorry. The rigorous way is to first define $Q_n$ on $\mathcal{F}_n$, then to claim that there is a $Q$ which equals $Q_n$ when restricted to $\mathcal{F}_n$. I should've be more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard example of a non-negative martingale $(X_n)$ with $EX_n=1$ for all $n$ converging almost surely to $X_\infty=0$. Here  $Q\{X_\infty=\infty\}=0$, $Q[\sup_n X_n=\infty]=0$  and $E_P[X_\infty]=0$.

Comment: Thank you! But the converse should be correct, yes?

Comment: The converse is true. @Gladiator